# How to set the button background image through code

Tags: java, android, button

I am using a `Button` created using following code

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setOnClickListener(newtodobtn);
btn.setText("New Todo");

btn.setBackgroundDrawable(new Button(this).getBackground());

ll.addView(btn);
```

I have an image in path `@drawable/new_todo_image` to set as background for the button. How to set it to the `Button` programmatically?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

for set background image for button which is in drawable folder then use below code

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_todo_image);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_todo_image));
```

Comment: as of 2014, this is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_todo_image));
```

Comment: I am getting following error :
The method setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_todo_image);
This code suits the requirement. And thanks for better suggestion

Comment: btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_todo_image);

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
     {
      mBtn.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_todo_image) );
     } 
    else
       {
       mBtn.setBackground( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_todo_image));
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

In android studio to set Button background Image write following code :

```
int image_resid = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("image_name", "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
button.setBackgroundResource(image_resid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your png files into Drawable folder, then try these codes:

```
Button buttonSES = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSES)    
buttonSES.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);  //image1.png
```