# Hot to set button background

Tags: android

I want to set button background from Java code I have this code

```
    public void Save(View sender){
    Button btn=(Button)sender;
    btn.setBackground(R.drawable.mybuttonbackground);
```

but this doesn't work and isn't compiled.

So How to set button background from Java Code

thank you for your answers.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the button background image through code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397788/how-to-set-the-button-background-image-through-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybuttonbackground);
```